# Editing Sharepoint List on page SP Online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to get the edit form dialog to get a list item id from a list view on a webpage to populate on button press.
For example, I have a list called 'Selection' and a page called 'Selector' where people would log in to the Selector page, which contains a list view webpart to the selection list - Ideally the person would tick an item and press a button on the page to display the edit form page (in a dialog)

I have found some code to get the list item id on checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function ShowSelectedItems() {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
  var key;
  for (key in selectedItems) {
   alert(selectedItems[key].id);
  }


 }</script>
 <input name="btnShowSelectedItems" id="btnShowSelectedItems"     onclick="ShowSelectedItems();"
```

and the code to display the edit form page in a dialog

```
href="javascript:displayLayover(&quot;/sites/Selection/Lists/Selection/EditForm.aspx?ID=XXX&IsDlg=1&quot;)">
```

But just don't know how to put 2 and 2 together

Thanks!

Comment: You can select multiple items using the selection checkboxes, but only one modal dialog can be displayed at a time. What do you want to happen when someone selects more than one item, then clicks the button to show the edit form?